# Extract string from address bar URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have the address bar URL as below;
https://subdomain.mysite.com/abc/xyz/MYID9878797878/page/#/route1/step1/step2

What is the best way to get "MYID9878797878" from this URL string ?

Should I use regex ?

Comment: with so much reputation comes so much responsibility.

Comment: @guradio I'm amazed as you're!

Answer (score 1):

```
var url = "https://subdomain.mysite.com/abc/xyz/MYID9878797878/page/#/route1/step1/step2";

var parameter3 = url.split('/')[5];
//OR var parameter3 = location.href.split('/')[5];

// console.log(parameter3) or alert(parameter3)
```

Comment: Is it possible to do without using split i.e. not being dependent on the index? I know that that it would always start with MYID

Comment: Okay, then please try the JavaScript String match() Method.

Comment: sample code var maches = url.match(/MYID(.*)\/page/);

Answer (score 0):

Well, if it's at the same part of the path you can do:

```
document.location.pathname.split('/')[3]
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work if it is always after that number of `/`:

```
var mystr = url.split('/')[5];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this
    console.log(location.href.split('/')[5]);